# How to go back to specific while loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

Can someone help me identify where the problem is? Whatever options I chose at the end in the Course/Student/Year level menu the program is always going back to the Year level loop.

Sorry for the messy program I'm still new, If you have time please help me fix my codes.

I'm required to do this in every course in our school so it'll be too long.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char crs = 'C';
        char yrr = 'Y';
        char Std = 'S';
        char inv = 'Y';
        int yrlvl, sections, students;
        ArrayList < String > yearlvl = new ArrayList < String > ();
        yearlvl.add("First Year");
        yearlvl.add("Second Year");
        yearlvl.add("Third Year");
        yearlvl.add("Fourth Year");
        yearlvl.add("Fifth Year");
        ArrayList < String > Sections = new ArrayList < String > ();
        String[] alphabet = {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J",
            "K",
            "L",
            "M",
            "N",
            "O",
            "P",
            "Q",
            "R",
            "S",
            "T",
            "U",
            "V",
            "W",
            "X",
            "Y",
            "Z"
        };
        ArrayList < String > SectionsName = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < String > Students = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < String > StudentsName = new ArrayList < String > ();
        while ((crs == 'C' || crs == 'c')) {
            System.out.println("========================================================================================");
            System.out.println("\nPamantasan ng Lungsod ng Marikina\n");
            System.out.println("Please choose a Course\n");
            System.out.println("Professional Programs \nA.Bachelor in Elementary Education (BEEd");
            System.out.println("\nEnter your letter of your choice:");
            char course = input.next().charAt(0);

            switch (course) {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    System.out.println("\nWelcome to College of Bachelor in Elementary Education!\nDo you want to get major in Special education? (Y for yes)");
                    char se = input.next().charAt(0);
                    if ((se == 'y' || se == 'Y')) {
                        System.out.println("\nYou've chosen to get the major in Special Education!");
                        while ((yrr == 'Y' || yrr == 'y')) {
                            System.out.println("\nChoose the year level you want to create new section:\n1.First Year\n2.Second Year\n3.Third Year\n4.Fourth Year\n5.Fifth Year\nEnter the number of your choice:");
                            yrlvl = input.nextInt();
                            while ((Std == 'S' || Std == 's')) {
                                System.out.println("\nHow many Section you want to create for " + yearlvl.get(yrlvl - 1) + "? \nEnter 0 if none");
                                sections = input.nextInt();
                                for (int i = 1; i <= sections; i++) {
                                    String xx;
                                    System.out.print("\nSection #" + i + "\nEnter The Section Name No Spaces: ");
                                    xx = input.next();
                                    SectionsName.add(xx);
                                } //for for (sections-i)
                                System.out.println("\nThe following are section/s for " + yearlvl.get(yrlvl - 1) + ".");
                                for (int i = 0; i < SectionsName.size(); i++) {
                                    System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "." + SectionsName.get(i));
                                } //for section names display
                                System.out.println("\nDo you want to add students or view students? ADD or DISPLAY:\nA. Add\n\nEnter your choice");
                                char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
                                if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a') {
                                    System.out.println("\nThe list of sections");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < SectionsName.size(); i++) {
                                        System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + SectionsName.get(i));
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of section in which you want to insert students");
                                    int i = input.nextInt();
                                    System.out.println("\nYou've chosen " + SectionsName.get(i - 1));
                                    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of students you want in " + SectionsName.get(i - 1) + "\nEnter 0 if none");
                                    int q = input.nextInt();
                                    ArrayList < String > StudNum = new ArrayList < String > (q);
                                    input.nextLine();
                                    for (int w = 0; w < q; w++) {
                                        System.out.println("Student #" + (w + 1) + " Name: ");
                                        String xxx = input.nextLine();
                                        StudNum.add(xxx);
                                    } //StudNum
                                    inv = 'Y';
                                    while (inv == 'Y') {
                                        System.out.println("\nReturn to A.Section Menu | B.Year Level Menu | C.Course Menu | D.Exit\nEnter the letter of your choice:");



//PROBLEM: When I Input letter B, I'm hoping it would go to Year level But it's going directly to Section Menu Same with Letter C



                                        char chs = input.next().charAt(0);
                                        switch (chs) {
                                            case 'a':
                                            case 'A':
                                                crs = 'x';
                                                yrr = 'x';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                Std = 'S';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                break;
                                            case 'b':
                                            case 'B':
                                                crs = 'x';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                yrr = 'Y';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                break;
                                            case 'c':
                                            case 'C':
                                                crs = 'c';
                                                crs = 'C';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                break;
                                            case 'd':
                                            case 'D':
                                                System.exit(0);
                                            default:
                                                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
                                                crs = 'c';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                Std = 'S';
                                                break;
                                        } //for switch(Chs)
                                    } //while(inv)
                                } //for while (Std)
                            } //for while (yrr)
                        } //if (choiceA)
                    } //for if (se)
            } // For while (crs)
        } // For Switch (course)

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read and hard to understand. Please format it properly.

Comment: Please explain what the program is supposed to do and what it is doing instead. Show what the input are clearly. If you have errors, mark where they are in the program.

Comment: I think this code is far from readable. I suggest you study the basics of Java. In my opinion, [the Java Tutorials from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html) is a pretty good start. You should study the basics of object-orientation, as well as organizing your code in methods and classes.

Comment: Whenever your code reaches a nesting that you need to put comments at the closing braces, consider splitting it into smaller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have run your code and tried to fix it as simple as possible. But your program would be better if you could create a class for section, a class for year, a class for student etc., Object Oriented Program would make your code more flexible.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char crs = 'C';
        char yrr = 'Y';
        char Std = 'S';
        char inv = 'Y';
        int yrlvl, sections, students;
        ArrayList<String> yearlvl = new ArrayList<String>();
        yearlvl.add("First Year");
        yearlvl.add("Second Year");
        yearlvl.add("Third Year");
        yearlvl.add("Fourth Year");
        yearlvl.add("Fifth Year");
        ArrayList<String> Sections = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] alphabet = {
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F",
                "G",
                "H",
                "I",
                "J",
                "K",
                "L",
                "M",
                "N",
                "O",
                "P",
                "Q",
                "R",
                "S",
                "T",
                "U",
                "V",
                "W",
                "X",
                "Y",
                "Z"
        };
        ArrayList<String> SectionsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Students = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> StudentsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        courseLoop : while ((crs == 'C' || crs == 'c'))
        {
            System.out.println("========================================================================================");
            System.out.println("\nPamantasan ng Lungsod ng Marikina\n");
            System.out.println("Please choose a Course\n");
            System.out.println("Professional Programs \nA.Bachelor in Elementary Education (BEEd");
            System.out.println("Enter your letter of your choice:");
            char course = input.next().charAt(0);

            switch (course)
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    System.out.println("\nWelcome to College of Bachelor in Elementary Education!\nDo you want to get major in Special education? (Y for yes)");
                    char se = input.next().charAt(0);
                    if ((se == 'y' || se == 'Y'))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYou've chosen to get the major in Special Education!");
                        yearLoop : while ((yrr == 'Y' || yrr == 'y'))
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nChoose the year level you want to create new section:\n1.First Year\n2.Second Year\n3.Third Year\n4.Fourth Year\n5.Fifth Year\nEnter the number of your choice:");
                            yrlvl = input.nextInt();
                            sectionsLoop : while ((Std == 'S' || Std == 's'))
                            {
                                System.out.println("How many Section you want to create for " + yearlvl.get(yrlvl - 1) + "? \nEnter 0 if none");
                                sections = input.nextInt();
                                for (int i = 1; i <= sections; i++)
                                {
                                    String xx;
                                    System.out.print("Section #" + i + "\nEnter The Section Name No Spaces: ");
                                    xx = input.next();
                                    SectionsName.add(xx);
                                } //for for (sections-i)
                                System.out.println("\nThe following are section/s for " + yearlvl.get(yrlvl - 1) + ".");
                                for (int i = 0; i < SectionsName.size(); i++)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(alphabet[i] + "." + SectionsName.get(i));
                                } //for section names display
                                System.out.println("\nDo you want to add students or view students? ADD or DISPLAY:\nA. Add\n\nEnter your choice");
                                char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
                                if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
                                {
                                    System.out.println("The list of sections");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < SectionsName.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + SectionsName.get(i));
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("Enter the number of section in which you want to insert students");
                                    int i = input.nextInt();
                                    System.out.println("You've chosen " + SectionsName.get(i - 1));
                                    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of students you want in " + SectionsName.get(i - 1) + "\nEnter 0 if none");
                                    int q = input.nextInt();
                                    ArrayList<String> StudNum = new ArrayList<String>(q);
                                    input.nextLine();
                                    for (int w = 0; w < q; w++)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Student #" + (w + 1) + " Name: ");
                                        String xxx = input.nextLine();
                                        StudNum.add(xxx);
                                    } //StudNum
                                    inv = 'Y';
                                    while (inv == 'Y')
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("\nReturn to A.Section Menu | B.Year Level Menu | C.Course Menu | D.Exit\nEnter the letter of your choice:");
                                        crs = 'x';
                                        yrr = 'x';
                                        Std = 'x';
                                        char chs = input.next().charAt(0);
                                        switch (chs)
                                        {
                                            case 'a':
                                            case 'A':
                                                crs = 'x';
                                                yrr = 'x';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                Std = 'S';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                continue sectionsLoop;
                                            case 'b':
                                            case 'B':
                                                crs = 'x';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                yrr = 'Y';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                continue yearLoop;
                                            case 'c':
                                            case 'C':
                                                crs = 'c';
                                                crs = 'C';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                Std = 's';
                                                inv = 'x';
                                                continue courseLoop;
                                            case 'd':
                                            case 'D':
                                                System.exit(0);
                                            default:
                                                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
                                                crs = 'c';
                                                yrr = 'y';
                                                Std = 'S';
                                                break;
                                        } //for switch(Chs)
                                    } //while(inv)
                                } //for while (Std)
                            } //for while (yrr)
                        } //if (choiceA)
                    } //for if (se)
            } // For while (crs)
        } // For Switch (course)

    }
}
```